# Asp.Net MVC: Serverside or Clientside Parsing HTML Content

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

What are the pros and cons of processing/creating/parsing HTML server- or clientside.

First Process:

1. Parsing the html-data on the serverside via Razor
2. Passing this HTML-code the clientside and include this

Second Process:

1. Passing data to the clientside
2. Parsing these for example with javascript for producing HTML-code

Currently, I find only Cons for the first one

1. The chunk of data is larger, because we are sending not only the
   data to the client
2. Parsing the data on the serverside costs more
   for the company.

Comment: This question is way too broad, it depends on the circumstances more then anything.

Comment: For example: I like to build something like a list of events. So I have to create for each event HTML with the data.

Comment: It's a fair question

Answer (score 1):

**For the Second Process:** The data and all its processes (business logic or sensitive data) will be available for the client to see.

Also, rendering time of the page will depend on the client's computer since its executed locally and not in the server.

My suggestions would be to stay server side to protect your data processing.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is mvc vs angular.  The difference for me is the indexing of pages by google and other web crawlers.  If that is not a concern I like to do as much as I can in the client, and angular or other such html frameworks provide the 'parsing' functionality, as well as two way binding, services, and a host of other features that make client side development in HTML a breeze.